# Trying to overwrite IE default system font with another system font not working only in IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, fonts

Currently my  font-family is set to Arial.  In IE11, the webpage font is set to Times New Roman.  Even though inspect element shows the font-family set to Arial, the UI displays Times New Roman.

And strangely, if I uncheck Arial in devtools, Arial displays correctly.  This is only happening in IE, Chrome, FF, Edge are all displaying Arial.

I have no issues using a web font with @font-face... just overwriting the browser's default system font with another system font.

Any ideas?

I don't think it matters, but I am using bootstrap with less.

```
// Fonts
@site-font: Arial !important ;
@site-font-bold: Arial !important ;
@site-font-light: Arial !important ;
@site-font-italic: Arial !important ;
@site-font-bold-italic: Arial !important ;
@site-font-light-italic: Arial !important ;
```

[inspect displays the font I have set in CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3yQs.png)

Comment: Can you post the CSS?

Comment: I have many less pages that point the font to a variable, so I have only set the variables to Arial in a custom less file such as:

font-family-base: Arial !important ;
site-font: Arial !important ;
site-font-bold: Arial !important ;
site-font-light: Arial !important ;
site-font-italic: Arial !important ;
site-font-bold-italic: Arial !important ;
site-font-light-italic: Arial !important ;
(all variables begin with "@" but this site isn't allowing that)

Comment: @gemArt, its best to put your code inside of the actual question and not in comments. Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45968908/edit) button and insert your code into the question. Indenting it by 4 spaces (or dragging over the text and click the "code" styling format) will allow it to appear in a nice organized block.

Answer (score 0):

MSIE,Edge and FX dev tools do not display the default userAgent style rules when you inspect an element.

All web browsers have a setting for the default font-family to use for web pages where none has been specified. (style rules cascade down from the default userAgent rules).

Only MSIE browsers have a user setting(s) to "Ignore font-styles specified on web pages" (Internet Options>General tab, Accessibility button). That is... over-ride the font-family rules specified on web pages with the font-family name that has been specified in IE's Font settings.... General tab of Internet Options>Fonts button.

All web browsers also have a user setting for the size of fonts to be displayed.

**When comparing the layout of your web page in different web browsers it is important that you configure each of your test browsers with the same default settings for fonts. For MSIE, also uncheck the options to "Ignore font-styles specified on web pages" and "Ignore font sizes specified on web pages".**

Web fonts can also fail. To trouble shoot blocked content and security issues in IE, first set Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages"...

Its a good idea to include a reproduction url or enough source code in your questions, so that we can test your code to see if its your coding or your testing/development environment browser settings.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  When you mentioned the browser setting to 'ignore font-styles..' I was like yes, that must be it!  But it was not - none of the ignore's were checked.I wish I could post a link but this is all internal at my work.

Answer (score 0):

Coworker helped me with this one, seems font-family: 'Arial' is not a natively supported font-family

See https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/fonts-and-formatting/web-browser-font-defaults/

The closest you would get without defining font-faces is to do font-family: 'sans-serif' (which defaults to using Arial font but that would have issues on some less-common browsers).

What you want is to declare a @font-face for each variant of Arial you want within your custom variables.less.  You may be able to get away with a single declaration, as I'm not sure what your use of Arial is throughout the site.

It will look something like

```
@font-face {
font-family: @font-family-base;
src: local("Arial");
}
```